# Passing function to overloaded method in Scala

Tags: scala

I've hit an interesting issue with passing function references to overloaded methods in Scala (Using 2.11.7)

The following code works as expected

```
def myFunc(a: Int, b: String): Double = {
  a.toDouble + b.toDouble
}


def anotherFunc(value: String, func: (Int, String) => Double) = {
  func(111, value)
}

anotherFunc("123123", myFunc)
```

But the following code doesn't compile

```
def myFunc(a: Int, b: String): Double = {
  a.toDouble + b.toDouble
}


def anotherFunc(value: String, func: (Int, String) => Double) = {
  func(111, value)
}

def anotherFunc(value: Int, func: (Int, String) => Double) = {
  func(value, "123123")
}

anotherFunc("123123", myFunc)
```

Compiler shouts the following

```
scala> anotherFunc("123123", myFunc)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("123123")
 required: Int
       anotherFunc("123123", myFunc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason but seems you have to write

```
anotherFunc("123123", myFunc _)
```

to make it work.

Comment: Would love to know why a partial application is required in this case

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Scala REPL? One of it's design decisions is that if you have two variables/functions with the same name defined then "last defined wins". In your case it is a function with Int parameter.

You can print all defined symbols in REPL using:

```
$intp.definedTerms.foreach(println)
```

Here someone had similar question: [Why its possible to declare variable with same name in the REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772320/why-its-possible-to-declare-variable-with-same-name-in-the-repl)

Comment: While different behavior - The code above fails in a class file as well and not only the REPL. It refuses to compile. I will edit my question to reflect that fact.